# Plain Text Tabular Parsing

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse an plain text table that I generated via a PDF. The data format is the typical invoice table. Using pdftotext along with PHP, I've iterated the relevant table rows into array elements. I need to parse these elements, breaking them into a multidimensional array for inserting into a database.

Below is an example of some data I will encounter:

```
05/18 TMobileRTR 10-100 PE Sold 5/17/2015 11:34 PM 5555556666 $75.00 8.75 % $68.44 $6.56
05/18 T-MobileGoSmt10-100 Sold 5/18/2015 3:20 PM 7775556666 $45.00 6.00 % $42.30 $2.70
05/18 Univision $10-100EX Sold 5/18/2015 6:23 AM 8885556666 $65.00 6.00 % $61.10 $3.90
05/15 NET10 $50 Unl RTR Sold 5/15/2015 6:00 PM 9995556666 $50.00 8.00 % $46.00 $4.00
05/15 RP $49.99 30D RTR Sold 5/15/2015 6:16 PM 1115556666 $49.99 8.00 % $45.99 $4.00 
05/16 Simple $40 TTD Sold 5/16/2015 1:42 PM 2225556666 $40.00 7.75 % $36.90 $3.10
```

**Considerations:**

Using explode to break it up by white space. However, there is to many variables to sanitize with this method.

I've been experimenting with regex patterns to accomplish this, however it isn't in my scope of knowledge to accomplish this.

My pattern I've attempt to procure is:

```
^(?<settlment>\d{2}[\/]\d{2})(?:\s)(?<product>.+?)(?:\s)(?<type>.+?)(?:\s)(?<transaction>\d{1-12}[\/]{1-31}[\/].[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9].+?)(?:\s)(?<control>\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b)(?:\s)(?<retail>[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})(?:\s)(?<discount>[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})(?:\s)(?<cost>[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})(?:\s)(?<commission>[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})$
```

I'm assuming regex is the best method to go about, however I need to refine my pattern.

The following is an associative breakdown so we can understand what I'm trying to convey here:

```
Settlement Date => 05/18 
Product => TMobileRTR 10-100 PE 
Type => Sold 
Transaction Date/Time => 5/17/2015 11:34 PM 
Control Number => 5555556666 
Retail => $75.00 
Discount => 8.75 % 
Cost => $68.44 
Commission => $6.56
```

That is how I need the data formatted for relational insert.

Comment: What is the expected result, what is "type" in particular?

Comment: It is next to impossible to write a regex for it without understanding what each part of each string means. Please explain. I think you will refine your regex yourself when you try explaining the meaning of each part :)

Comment: Unclear, what is the question ?

Comment: I've added some revisions to my original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now imagine someone having to debug your code and seeing that regex. Good luck without an external tool. This is an excellent example where I'd avoid regular expressions and go for a dedicated parser class which uses plain old PHP combining `explode` (space as a delimiter) and `is_*` functions to extract data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your regex and got it to match, however you might have to refine it to extract the groups you need!

EDIT: Updated with the exact groups proposed:
http://regexr.com/3b217
[image]

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted. However, this didn't work for me. Understandably because I didn't convey the question properly. Thanks